# How to run multiple AND in grep command

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to run multiple AND combination in grep command, I was able to run using two patterns:

`grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2' filename`

Is it possible to use three or four patterns using the above method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the order of the patterns is fixed then you can easily use `grep` as in:

```
grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2.*pattern3'
```

But in case that all patterns must be present and they may appear in any order then you get combinatorical complexity; e.g. for two patterns:

```
grep -E '(pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1)'
```

(and for three patterns you'd have already eight combinations).

In such cases (i.e. when using `grep`) it's better to cascade the calls in a pipeline of one `grep` instance per pattern:

```
grep pattern1 <infile | grep pattern2 | grep pattern3
```

Each instance will filter only the lines that match their pattern, and the overall result will contain only lines that have all the patterns.

A better approach that leads to the clearest solution is to use `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && /pattern3/'
```

where the ordering would not matter in such an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can construct any regular expression you want and use it as the pattern in a `grep` command. It simply has to be a legal regular expression.